# How do I install Wine on Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, wine

I am trying to install Wine on Amazon Linux AMI.

First I did:

```
   sudo yum install wine
```

It said "No wine package available."

Then I did the following:

```
   sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
   sudo yum install wine -y
```

At the end of the output I get the following:

```
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: wine-core-1.0.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgphoto2_port.so.0
Error: Package: wine-esd-1.0.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libesd.so.0
Error: Package: wine-core-1.0.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libgphoto2.so.2
Error: Package: wine-desktop-1.0.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: desktop-file-utils >= 0.8
Error: Package: wine-esd-1.0.1-1.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: libaudiofile.so.0
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can you help me to get Wine installed and running?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no wine package for Amazon Linux.

You can always install from source:
http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/installing-wine-source

Just install the dependencies needed to build from source with yum.

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux and it is available thru' EPEL.

Answer (score -1):

What is the version of Amazon Linux you are using ?

Recent Amazon AMI's are based on EL6 upstream. EPEL 6 bundles wine.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score -1):

I ran across this page while looking for an answer. Here is what I eventually found out:

1. Modify /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo. Under the section marked [epel], change enabled=0 to enabled=1. You can do this with the command "sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo"
2. Install WINE with "sudo yum install wine"
3. Install any dependencies

See this page for reference:
http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/